# Implementing a switch statement in a CSHTML page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to do something different. I have a view that contains an Id. Based on the value of the Id I want to change my heading that appears. Something like:

```
@{ switch id
   case "test": @;<h1>Test Site</h1>
   case "prod": @:<h1>Prod Site</h1>
   break;
}
```

I have quite a lot of case conditions so I though use of case would be best. Can anyone suggest how I can do this and get it to work? I am getting a lot of syntax errors so I think maybe it's not coded well.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Your switch needs to be completely enclosed in a block and it needs to be "broken" properly:

```
// Use the @{ } block and put all of your code in it
@{
    switch(id)
    {
        case "test":
            // Use the text block below to separate html elements from code
            <text>
                <h1>Test Site</h1>
            </text>
            break;  // Always break each case
        case "prod":
            <text>
                <h1>Prod Site</h1>
            </text>
            break;
        default:
            <text>
                <h1>WTF Site</h1>
            </text>
            break;                   
    }
}
```

Because the `<h1>` tags are enclosed html blocks by themselves, you may not need the `<text>` blocks for separation. It's just my habit to include them.

Comment: There is no need to enclose the entire switch statement in a @{} block.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `<text></text>`. It's not needed if you are using html tags. See the answer from @yoelhalb below.

Answer (score 62):

```
@switch (id)
{
    case "test": <h1>Test Site</h1>
    break;
    case "prod": <h1>Prod Site</h1>
    break;
}
```

There is no need to enclose the entire switch statement in a `@{}` block, (unlike Joel Etherton's post)

Your errors are basically regular syntax errors and have nothing to do with razor;

1. the variable wasn't in parenthesis
2. the body of switch wasn't in brackets
3. no "break" after the first statement.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't answer your question, as indicated by the question's title, but it does solve the problem you described in the body of the question.

Use a view model class as the view's model and add a method that includes the `switch` statement. Then just call the method from the view via `@Model.MethodWithSwitchStatement()`. [The `id` can be saved in the view model object.]

Comment: THAT'S the right way to solve the problem described in the OP

Answer (score 4):

```
@{
    String txt;
    switch (id) {
        case "test":
            txt = "Test";
            break;
        case "prod":
            txt = "Prod";
            break;
        default:
            txt = "WTF";
    }
}

<h1>@txt Site</h1>
```

**The Most Concise**: Less redundant or repetitive code and markup.